# Como hacer que la consulta tome en cuenta los valores nulos

Tags: sql-server

estoy haciendo un pequeña pequeña consulta en SQL Server y me estoy dando cuenta que no me esta mostrando los registros que tienen valor nulo en el campo Estatus.
Este el código de la consulta:

```
SELECT d.Precio,c.Descripcion AS Corrida,SUM(d.TotalPares) AS Pares,SUM(d.Costo) AS 
Importe, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
FROM DFacturas d
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Producto p ON d.Producto = p.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Corrida c ON p.Id_Corrida = c.Id_Corrida
WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
AND d.Estatus<>'C'
GROUP BY d.Precio,c.Descripcion, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
ORDER BY d.Fecha asc
```

En la consulta estoy diciendo que me muestre los registros cuando el valor de campo Estatus sea diferente de "C", pero como puedo hacerle para que me muestre los registros que tienen valor NULL en el campo Estatus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregar una condicion adicional

```
SELECT d.Precio,c.Descripcion AS Corrida,SUM(d.TotalPares) AS Pares,SUM(d.Costo) AS 
Importe, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
FROM DFacturas d
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Producto p ON d.Producto = p.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Corrida c ON p.Id_Corrida = c.Id_Corrida
WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
AND ( d.Estatus<>'C' OR d.Estatus IS NULL)
GROUP BY d.Precio,c.Descripcion, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
ORDER BY d.Fecha asc;
```

El problema es que al comparar valores con NULLs, el resultado no es falso ni positivo sino *desconocido*. Esto es algo que se debe de mantener en cuenta cada vez que compares con columnas o valores que puedan contener nulos.

Comment: Esto creo que no funciona, asi te va a devolver valores distintos de C pero nulos tambien. Deberia colocar un AND aparte donde d.estatus <> NULL o NOT NULL

Comment: *pero nulos también*... @ErnestoRincon No es eso lo que OP pide cuando dice *"Como hacer que la consulta tome en cuenta los **valores nulos**"*?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, pedía para que tambien me mostrara los registros que en el campo estatus tienen Null, asi que la respuesta esta bien, muchas gracias

Comment: @ErnestoRincon El usar `d.estatus <> NULL` nunca regresará resultados porque nunca será verdadero. Tampoco será falso, solo será desconocido.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta al problema es relativamente sencilla, pero que te hayas visto en esta situación es un indicador de que el concepto detrás aún no ha sido bien comprendido y este resulta de vital importancia al trabajar con bases de datos relacionales.

Por eso, empiezo mi respuesta haciendo un pequeño y necesario tour por la teoría. Mi recomendación, tanto para el autor de la pregunta, como para cualquier persona que haya llegado aquí enfrentando un problema similar, es que no salte a leer las soluciones puntuales y que se de un tiempo para leer las explicaciones que doy a continuación.

### Significado del valor `NULL`

En general, en SQL, todos los tipos de datos soportan este valor especial `null` que tiene ese significado de *valor desconocido* o *valor no establecido*.

Así, en una fila de una tabla, en una columna de cualquier tipo puede encontrarse dicho valor especial `null` que debe interpretarse como que nunca se le dio un valor a dicha columna o que su valor no es conocido.

De manera análoga, cualquier variable puede tener el valor especial `null`. Si hablamos de SQL Server específicamente, esto es válido:

```
declare @i int;

if @i is null
  print 'i es null'
else 
  print 'i es ' + cast(@i as varchar);
```

Y produce la salida:

```
i es null
```

### Lógica de 3 valores

Justo gracias a la existencia del valor especial `null` SQL utiliza una lógica de 3 valores, pues como en otros tipos de datos, en valores booleanos existen el tradicional falso (`false`) y verdadero (`true`), pero también el valor especial `null`, que significa *desconocido* o *no establecido*.

Así:

- todo operador que de un resultado booleano puede devolver verdadero, falso o NULL. Entre estos operadores están los de comparación (`=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`) y los de pertenencia (`in`, `not in`) entre otros.
- Los operadores lógicos como  `and`, `or` y `not` tienen tablas de verdad que toman en cuenta los valores `null`.

###### Operadores que devuelven valores booleanos

La regla general es que, por ejemplo, si comparas un valor conocido con uno desconocido, no se puede saber con precisión el resultado, y por tanto es desconocido.

Veamos algunos ejemplos de operadores:

- De igualdad:

  - `1 = 1` devuelve `true`
  - `1 = 3` devuelve `false`
  - `1 = null` devuelve `null`
  - `null = null` devuelve `null` (ojo con esto)
- De desigualdad:

  - `1 <> 1` devuelve `false`
  - `1 <> 3` devuelve `true`
  - `1 <> null` devuelve `null`
  - `null <> null` devuelve `null` (ojo con esto)
- Mayor qué:

  - `5 > 1` devuelve `true`
  - `5 > 10` devuelve `false`
  - `5 > null` devuelve `null`
  - `null > 10` también devuelve `null`
- `in`

  - `5 in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` devuelve `true`
  - `5 in (1, 2, 3)` devuelve `false`
  - `null in (1, 2, 3)` devuelve `null`
  - `null in (1, 2, 3, null)` devuelve `null` (por las mismas razones de la igualdad).

Si analizas con cuidado los resultados, encontrarás que hacen sentido con el significado de `null`. Cambia en cada una de las expresiones `null` por `desconocido` y se verá más claro.

Aún así, una de las cosas que normalmente cuesta un poco más realizar es que `null = null` no puede devolver verdadero, aunque a ambos lados del operador de igualdad esté el valor `null`. Esto cobra sentido si piensas que `null` no es un valor como tal, sino que significa `ausencia de valor` y, principalmente que también significa `desconocido`. Si no conoces el valor de cada lado de la igualdad, realmente no puedes decir si son iguales o no, y por tanto, el resultado de la comparación también es `desconocido`.

Por la misma razón `null in (1, 2, 3, null)` devuelve `null`.

###### Operadores `is null`

Para salvar la situación anterior y porque hay muchas ocasiones en las que debemos comprobar si una variable o un valor almacenado en una tabla tiene el valor especial `null` existe el operador `is null`. Probablemente este es el único operador (o de los pocos) que solo puede devolver `true` o `false`, pero no `null`.

- `null is null` devuelve `true`
- `5 is null` devuelve `false`

###### Tablas de verdad de los operadores lógicos

**and**

| a | b | a and b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true |
| true | false | false |
| true | null | null |
| false | true | false |
| false | false | false |
| false | null | null |
| null | true | null |
| null | false | null |
| null | null | null |

**or**

| a | b | a or b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true |
| true | false | true |
| true | null | true |
| false | true | true |
| false | false | false |
| false | null | null |
| null | true | true |
| null | false | null |
| null | null | null |

**xor**

| a | b | a or b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | false |
| true | false | true |
| true | null | null |
| false | true | true |
| false | false | false |
| false | null | null |
| null | true | null |
| null | false | null |
| null | null | null |

**not**

| a | not a |
| --- | --- |
| true | false |
| false | true |
| null | null |

### Función `coalesce()`

La función `coalesce()` es parte del estándar SQL y soportada por múltiples fabricantes. Su funcionamiento es bastante sencillo. La función recibe cualquier cantidad de parámetros, de cualquier tipo de datos y, de ellos, devuelve el primero que tenga un valor distinto de `null`. Si todos los parámetros recibidos son `null`, devuelve `null`.

Muchas veces se utiliza `coalesce()` para obtener un valor distinto de null de manera forzosa, por ejemplo, con un valor default que siempre se pasa como último parámetro.

También se puede utilizar para sustituir el valor `null` a la hora de utilizar operadores aritméticos o de concatenación, para evitar que el resultado de toda la expresión sea `null`.

Por ejemplo, podemos obtener una salida válida si cambiamos el código del primer ejemplo por:

```
declare @i int;
print 'i es ' + coalesce(cast(@i as varchar), 'null');
```

### Cláusulas `where`

El funcionamiento de la cláusula `where` es bastante sencillo y lo podríamos resumir en:

Si existe una cláusula `where`, esta debe tener una expresión que genere un único valor booleano y en el resultado de la consulta **se incluirán solamente aquellas filas para las que el resultado de evaluar esta expresión sea `true`**.

Es muy importante tener en cuenta la lógica de 3 valores cuando construyes sentencias `where`. Tan importante como conocer la estructura de las tablas o vistas que estás involucrando en la consulta. Si no lo haces, es fácil excluir filas que quisieras incluir porque el resultado de la expresión que utiliza operadores de comparación y operadores lógicos, en lugar de devolver `true` devuelva `null`, que es justamente el caso planteado en la pregunta.

De manera general, hay que tomar en consideración esto para toda columna que pueda contener valores nulos. Es decir, toda columna que no tenga una restricción `not null`.

### Análisis del caso puntual de la pregunta

Veamos detalladamente qué está ocurriendo en el caso de la pregunta. El autor ha indicado que quisiera incluir las filas que tengan valor `null` en la columna `d.Estatus`, pero que no aparecen.

> ```
> WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
> AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
> AND d.Estatus<>'C'
> ```

Si revisamos la cláusula `where`, teniendo presente todo lo dicho hasta ahora, salta a la vista la tercera condición `AND d.Estatus<>'C'`. Sabemos que si `d.Estatus` es `null`, el operador `<>` nos va a devolver `null` para la expresión `null <> 'C'`.

Para una fila que cumpla las primeras dos condiciones y el campo d.Estatus contenga `null`, vamos a tener una expresión que se resume a:

```
where true and true and null
```

De la tabla de verdad del operador `and`, y sabiendo que se evalúa de izquierda a derecha, nos va quedando:

```
where true and null
```

y finalmente

```
where null
```

Como dije antes, se incluyen solamente aquellas filas para las que la expresión evalúa a `true`, por lo que esta fila es excluida.

### La solución al problema

A estas alturas, las posibles soluciones al problema debieran resultar triviales para el lector (si aún no, quizás falte leer y reflexionar otra vez el texto de la respuesta, sin importar si esta es la quinta vez que llegas a este punto).

- Podría resolverse con el uso de `coalesce`, por ejemplo:

  ```
  WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
  AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
  AND coalesce(d.Estatus, '') <>'C'
  ```

  En este caso, cada vez que una fila contenga `null` en esa columna se usará el valor *default* '' para la comparación, y `'' <> 'C'` va a devolver `true`.
- También puede resolverse usando el operador `is null` y el operador lógico `or` para construir una expresión que devuelva `true` en caso de ser null, `true` en caso de ser distinto de `C` y falso si es igual a `C`:

  ```
  WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
  AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
  AND (d.Estatus is null or d.Estatus <>'C')
  ```

### Bonus track: null y otros operadores y funciones:

`null` también tiene un comportamiento especial con el resto de operadores y funciones. El principio es el mismo y se basa en que null significa `desconocido`.

- Operadores aritméticos:

  - `5 + null` devuelve `null`
  - `null * 3` devuelve `null`
- Concatenación: En general, concatenar cualquier cadena con `null` devuelve `null`, por ejemplo `'hola' + nombre` va a devolver `null` si nombre es `null`.
- Funciones: En general, la mayoría de las funciones van a devolver un valor consistente con el precepto de que null es desconocido. Así, probablemente devuelvan `null` si alguno de sus parámetros es `null`, siempre que cumpla con el contrato.

Por la misma razón, si volvemos al ejemplo del inicio, el código a continuación produce como salida una línea vacía:

```
declare @i int;
print 'i es ' + cast(@i as varchar);
```

Esto es porque la función `cast` recibe `null` y, por tanto, devuelve `null`, y la concatenación `'i es ' + null` convierte en `null` toda la cadena, con lo que no hay nada que imprimir y print solo hace el avance de línea.

Comment: Que buena e informativa respuesta. Esto es un Master Class. Gracias.

Comment: Muy buena explicación. Sin embargo, preferiría evitar la solución que usa `COALESCE` puesto que limita el uso de índices en la consulta. Aunque sea poco probable que se usen índices para este caso, es una buena práctica evitar usar funciones en columnas en la clausula `WHERE`.

Comment: Es un buen apunte, la respuesta está enfocada en la lógica de 3 valores y ya era larga para hablar de consideraciones de desempeño. En SQL Server se pueden crear índices basados en expresiones, por lo que el uso de coalesce no necesariamente implica que no se usen estos. Por otro lado, habría que ver el volumen de datos y la estructura para hablar de optimizar el desempeño.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar un AND adicional indicando que d.estatus no sea nulo.

```sql
    SELECT d.Precio,c.Descripcion AS Corrida,SUM(d.TotalPares) AS Pares,SUM(d.Costo) AS 
    Importe, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
    FROM DFacturas d
    INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Producto p ON d.Producto = p.Id_Producto
    INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Corrida c ON p.Id_Corrida = c.Id_Corrida
    WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
    AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
    AND (d.Estatus<>'C' OR d.Estatus IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY d.Precio,c.Descripcion, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
    ORDER BY d.Fecha asc
```

Si en cambio deseas que si te muestre los que posean estatus nulo:

```sql
    SELECT d.Precio,c.Descripcion AS Corrida,SUM(d.TotalPares) AS Pares,SUM(d.Costo) AS 
    Importe, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
    FROM DFacturas d
    INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Producto p ON d.Producto = p.Id_Producto
    INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy..Corrida c ON p.Id_Corrida = c.Id_Corrida
    WHERE p.Id_Linea = 196
    AND CONVERT(DATE, d.Fecha) BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '30/06/2023'
    AND (d.Estatus<>'C' OR d.Estatus IS NULL)
    GROUP BY d.Precio,c.Descripcion, d.Fecha, d.Estatus
    ORDER BY d.Fecha asc
```

Comment: En la primer consulta la condición que agregaste es redundante. En la segunda consulta nunca tendrás resultados porque un estatus no puede ser al mismo tiempo distinto de una constante y nulo.