# omitir varias columnas con datos dentro de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy aprendiendo SQL Workbench, y necesito hacer una consulta donde tengo que omitir más de una columna que contenga datos dentro de una misma tabla, por ejemplo:

```
Select id, nombre, apellido, edad, dni, inquilino, propietario
from usuario
```

Por ejemplo, dentro de la consulta necesito ver todos los registros donde no tenga datos en la columna de inquilino, ni propietario.

Answer (score 0):

Solo para aclarar la terminología, no omites columnas.

Lo que quieres hacer es excluir **filas** del resultado, en base a dichas columnas.

Para ello te vales de la cláusula `where`.

Esta contiene una expresión que se evalúa a un valor booleano. Dentro del resultado de la consulta se incluyen aquellas filas para las que el resultado de dicha expresión es `True`.

Así, para excluir las filas que no tienen información en la columna `Propietario` puedes usar la expresión

```
where propietario is not null
```

Y para excluir las filas que tampoco tienen información en la columna inquilino, valerte del operador lógico `and`, así

```
where propietario is not null
  and inquilino is not null
```

Esta consulta excluirá las filas que no tienen información en ambas columnas, pero incluirá aquellas que tienen información en alguna de las dos.

Te dejo un enlace a una respuesta donde encontrarás información útil sobre la [lógica de 3 estados de SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/599733/21)